# How to obtain current language in polyglossia

Tags: xetex, languages, polyglossia

How to obtain the current language set by `\setotherlanguage{english}` ?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xpg@other@language}{czech}}{A}{B} %macro doesn't exist
\setotherlanguage{english}
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xpg@other@language}{czech}}{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

I want output like AB. But macro `\xpg@other@language` does not exist and documentation is very poor. `\xpg@main@language` returns `czech` as I expected.

Comment: There can be more than one "other" language, so the equal test doesn't make sense. What are you trying to achieve? Beside this your document doesn't load the ifthen package, and your are not making @ a letter before the tests.

Comment: Ok, the question might be: How to obtain `english` just before `\end{document}`? I'm trying to distinguish between languages in my own-written macros. Of course you are right with `\makeatletter` and `ifthenelse` but this mess doesn't change a meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\iflanguage{czech}{czech}{no}

\selectlanguage{english}

\iflanguage{czech}{czech}{no}

\end{document}
```

[image]